# .NET - Add Icon - Fixed Tool Window

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on .NET 2.0 with C#. I am using Form Border Style as "FixedToolWindow".
I am not able to add icon with this property.

Is it possible to add icon with this property? If so, give me a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tool windows don't use icons.

For a similar style, you could set the window style to FixedSingle and disable the Min/Max buttons instead.

Comment: In that also it is possible to drag window from the corner. I don't want the windows to be drag. Any other way is present?

Comment: @informative - FixedSingle prevents the window from being resized.

Comment: But my taskbar gets invisible when I make the window state to be maximized. What can I do for that?

Comment: @informative - It behaves in the same way as FixedToolWindow would.

Comment: @informative: why would you allow a tool window to be maximized?

Comment: Now I used Fixed Single and set the MaximizeBox property to False as Barry told. It works fine as I thought. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

No. Windows does not draw an icon for `FixedToolWindow`. There are other options including drawing your own window, but that could be tedious.